# IBM Domino - Authentication with IBM Domino LDAP

Tags: c#, .net, lotus-domino

We want to authenticate user in our mobile application against a Domino server configured with LDAP.
We have read some [other](https://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21295968) [articles](https://www.dalsgaard-data.eu/blog/login-logout-when-using-ajax-against-domino/) and know that it is possible to authentication using username and password in the URL.

**Problems:**

- We have no experience with IBM Domino
- We don't know the exact config on the server.
- The document is quite old and not official.

**Questions:**

- Is this the only way to authenticate with the server?
- Are there any different configurations (e.g. basic authentication disabled,...) for this solution not to work?
- Is there any official documentation on how to do this?

Comment: Your mobile application is not a Domino or XPages application? So in principle you want to authenticate with "some" LDAP server, and you don't use anything on the Domino server? Maybe this document helps, as a starting point: https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/da/SSKTMJ_9.0.1/admin/conf_theldapservice_c.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The articles you linked to are not about LDAP authentication. They are about authentication via HTTP requests. You can certainly do that, but it isn't LDAP and you'll have to know more about the Domino server configuration. For instance, you'll have to know if the Domino server is actually running the HTTP task, if it is, you'll have to know what authentication methods are configured for it.

If you want to do LDAP authentication, and if the Domino server is actually running the LDAP task, then Domino LDAP works the same way that other LDAP servers work. You open an LDAP connection to the server using a DN that identifies the user, and you send the password with the [bind](https://ldap.com/the-ldap-bind-operation/) request. Your mobile toolkit probably provides tools for this.

Comment: Thank you, I didn't realize that. So what we need now is only the LDAP schema and access to the server, right?We will have an intermediate server for authenticating, so what the user use (mobile app or web) is irrelevant, right?

Comment: I don't think you need the entire LDAP schema. You do need to know the DN format the server will accept for a bind request. Something like cn=theUsersShortname,o=theOrganizationName may be sufficient, but that's just off the top of my head. And to be honest, I always have to experiment a little bit using my favorite LDAP client to see what works. If you have to send an actual query along with the bind request, the usual thing to do is just query for the user's own attributes via something like (&(cn=userShortName)(objectClass='Person')).

Comment: Thank you, I was stuck with how to authenticate with Domino and completely forgot about research on what LDAP is.